# Laravel validation JSON response order

Tags: json, laravel, validation, response

I have a validation.

```php
$request->validate([
    'bike_brand_id' => 'required',
    'bike_type_id' => 'required',
    'bike_gender_id' => 'required',
    'bike_size_id' => 'required',
    'bike_color_id' => 'required',
    'bike_brake_id' => 'required',
]);
```

The JSON response from Laravel always returns in alphabetical order like this;

[image]

What I need is the response to be in the order of the validation rules.

(Btw. the php response returned in variable $errors by default is in correct order)

Comment: instead why don't you just base the validation logic that clearly needs this, to access the validation rules on the key

Comment: The preview tab in google chrome dev tools orders the list in the preview. You should check the raw response instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I indeed realized that the console preview orders the errors alphabetically, while the actual returned errors are in correct order